# How can I delete a stored procedure on a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers, sequelpro

I have a table where I can't duplicate a row because one of the fields has a `stored procedure`, named `items.calcPrice`, on it that no longer exists.

Here's the MySQL command:

```
INSERT INTO items (folder_id)
VALUES (56)
```

the error message says, `"Couldn't write row. FUNCTION items.calcPrice does not exist."`

How do I identify and delete this `stored procedure` on my table? I have 2 fields which have a "price" value so I'm not sure which field this `procedure` is operating on.

Comment: Please paste the statement you are executing which gives rise to that error.

Comment: i'm using mysqlPro so i just have to click a button to create a new row, but give me a second to reproduce with a SQL command...

Comment: Are there any before/after insert triggers on that table?  `SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE Event = 'INSERT' AND Table = 'mytable'`?

Comment: hmm, its saying, `SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE Event = 'INSERT' AND Table = 'mytable'` isn't the right syntax, is that MySQL compatible?

Comment: sorry to those reading this thread, its **not** mysqlPro but rather Sequel Pro

Comment: Yes - [see the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-triggers.html).  Just do `SHOW TRIGGERS` without the `WHERE` clause and see what turns up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11108/discussion-between-eggyal-and-tim-peterson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our discussion in chat, it appears you have a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger called `Items_Trigger` defined on this table, which attempts to call the function to which your question refers.

To delete the trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER Items_Trigger;
```

Comment: Do not delete triggers until you know why they are there.

Comment: @HLGEM: Agreed - in this case, we covered that in our chat: "*i can delete all this stuff i don't need it anymore*" and, on further prompting, "*it's old logic we don't need anymore*".

Comment: I just wanted future readers to be aware that this is a dangerous practice if you don't know that the trigger is no longer needed.

Comment: @HLGEM thanks for your concern. These were very old rules which we aren't using anymore. Thanks for the note for future readers.